Published outlook add-in blocked by untrusted certificate
I developed an Outlook add-in. I have deployed all its files to a app service and it accessible through the browser. In my manifest.xml, I point to the files on this app service. However, I am getting errors about the certificate (in Outlook, not in my browser). I am not sure why, and I can not find out how to solve this. For reference, this is my xml with changes urls:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
  xsi:type="MailApp">

  <Id>myid</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.6</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Contoso Projects"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Contoso developed"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://myurl/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://myurl/assets/icon-128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.nl"/>
  
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://myurl/</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://myurl/src/taskpane/taskpane.html"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit"/>
  </Rule>
  
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- Link to the Function File -->
            <FunctionFile resid="FunctionFile.Url"/>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgComposeGroup">
                  <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <!-- ItemSend Event -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
              <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="checkBccBeforeSend" />
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://myurl/assets/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://myurl/assets/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://myurl/assets/icon-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://myurl/commands.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://myurl/src/taskpane/taskpane.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://myurl/src/function/function.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-Ins"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Contoso Projects"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Displays Contoso Projects."/>
          <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>


I tried updating my add-in. I did this multiple times and am now on version 1.0.0.6 of my add-in. I tried to see topics about it, but they were all about local development. My add-in is published.
Thank you in advance.
